# Cassandra Compaction takes all the resources and leads to node failure

Tags: cassandra

I met very strange problem during testing cassandra. I have a very simple column family that stores video data (keys point to time period and there is only one column containing ~2MB video for this period).

**Use Case**

I start to load data using Hector API (round-robin) to 6 empty nodes (8GB RAM for Cassandra)- load is run in 4 threads adding 4 rows in second for each thread.

After a while (running load for hour or so) near 100-200 GB are added to the node (depending on the replication factor) and then one or several nodes become unreachable. (no pinging just reboot helps)

**Why Compaction**

I do use tiered-level compaction and monitoring the system(Debian) i can see that it actually not writes but compaction that takes almost all resources (disk, memory) and cause server to refuse writes and than fail.

After like 30-40 minutes of test compaction tasks just cannot be handled and get queued. Interesting thing is that there are no deletes and updates  - so compaction just reads/writes data again and again without bringing actual value to me (like it can be compacted once in the evening).

When i slow down the pace - i.e running 2 threads with 1 second delay things go better but whether it still be working when i have 20TB not 100 GB on a node.

Is Cassandra optimized for such type of workload? How the resources are normally distributed between compaction and reads/writes?

**Update**
Update of network driver solved problem with unreachable cluster

Thanks,
Sergey.

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra will use up to `in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb` memory for a compaction.  It is routine to have compaction running while reads and writes are served simultaneously.  It is also normal that compaction can fall behind if you continue to throw writes at it as fast as possible; if your read workload requires that compaction be up to date or close to it at all times, then you'll need a larger cluster to spread the load around more machines.

Recommended amount of disk per node for online queries is up to 500GB, maybe 1TB if you're pushing it.  Remember that this amount of data will have to be rebuilt if a node fails.  Typical Cassandra workloads are CPU-bound or iops-bound, not disk-space bound, so you won't be able to make good use of that space anyway.

(It's also possible to do batch analytics against Cassandra, which we do with the [Cassandra Filesystem](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-file-system-design), in which case higher disk:cpu ratios are desirable, but we use a custom compaction strategy for that as well.)

It's not clear from your report why a server would become unreachable.  This is really an OS-level problem.  (Are you swapping? Disabling swap would be a good first step.)

Comment: Thank you @jbellis, network driver upgrade solved cluster hanging, compaction question it is still open - as my workload doesn't imply deletes or updates (only TTL set for 3 months) and that i work with one column family it seems natural to compact data only to some extent (i.e. compact up to 200-300 GB) - because further compaction will not give me much benefit from read performance however will imply heavy workload especially with major compactions. I consider something like **segmentation** - when internally column family is split by some attribute to minor ones can address this

Comment: @jbellis Is this custom compaction strategy proprietary or can we find it somewhere? I also use Cassandra as block storage and would benefit from a compaction strategy customized for it. Thanks.